# One layout over another layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I need one layout over another layout (they can have any heights), like this:

[image]

When screen become smaller, I need that brown layout become lower, like this:

[image]

I have this code to do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:gravity="center">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:background="#dd6600">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="One"/>
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:background="#bbbbbb">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:text="Another"/>
    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

On small heights it works fine, but on big screens I have this:

[image]

Can you help me please with this?

Comment: tried using Relativelayout instead as the parent layout?

Comment: @Roljhon I've tried it, but it didn't work like on the second pic

Answer (score 0):

you could benefit from `CoordinatorLayout` [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout.html) to do such effects

Comment: I have no idea how to use it in this case

Answer (score 0):

Use Linear layout with percentage weights, so that percent of screen covered will always be same despite of resolution as in

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="top"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight ="0.6"
        android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
        android:background="#dd6600">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:text="One"/>
    </FrameLayout>
<LinearLayout/>

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="1">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight ="0.6"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:background="#bbbbbb">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:text="Another"/>
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:gravity="center">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|center_horizontal"
    android:background="#dd6600">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="One"/>
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:background="#bbbbbb">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:text="Another"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Use `RelativeLayout` and add `android:layout_marginTop="70dp"` to second child of `RelativeLayout`. You can change margin as per your requirement.